# How is this custom md5 hash algorithm being implemented?

Tags: c++, hash, cuda, md5

First off, my ultimate goal is to implement an md5 hashing algorithm on a cuda-enabled graphics card. Yes, I know it has been done already.

Since the code in question is fairly lengthy, here is a link (this is not my code): 
http://majuric.org/software/cudamd5/source/cudamd5-v1.2.1/cuda_md5_gpu.cu

The majority of the code follows Wikipedia's prototype. However, it begins to differ at this point:

```
static const uint rconst_cpu[16] = {
     7, 12, 17, 22,   5,  9, 14, 20,   4, 11, 16, 23,   6, 10, 15, 21
};
```

Obviously, each "grouping" simply needs to be repeated four times.  Going along in the code, it reaches this point:

```
__device__ inline uint r(const uint i) {
   return rconst[(i / 16) * 4 + i % 4];
}

__device__ inline uint &getw(uint *w, const int i)
{
    return w[(i+threadIdx.x) % 16];
}

__device__ inline uint getw(const uint *w, const int i) // const- version
{
     return w[(i+threadIdx.x) % 16];
}


__device__ inline uint getk(const int i)
{
  return k[i];  // Note: this is as fast as possible (measured)
}

 __device__ void step(const uint i, const uint f, const uint g, uint &a, uint &b, uint &c, uint &d, const uint *w)
 {
   uint temp = d;
   d = c;
   c = b;
   b = b + leftrotate((a + f + getk(i) + getw(w, g)), r(i));
   a = temp;
}
```

I'm not certain what these functions are doing - especially `r().` In addition, what does `w[(i+threadIdx.x) % 16];` mean? I'm aware that `threadIdx.x` is unique to cuda, but I jumped into this language yesterday.

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Edit: This is code:

```
// CUDA MD5 hash calculation implementation (A: mjuric@ias.edu).
//
// A very useful link: http://people.eku.edu/styere/Encrypt/JS-MD5.html
//

#define RSA_KERNEL md5_v2

#include <stdio.h>
#include "cutil.h"

typedef unsigned int uint;

//
// On-device variable declarations
//

extern __shared__ uint memory[];    // on-chip shared memory
__constant__ uint k[64], rconst[16];    // constants (in fast on-chip constant cache)
__constant__ uint target[4];        // target hash, if searching for hash matches

//
// MD5 magic numbers. These will be loaded into on-device "constant" memory
//
   static const uint k_cpu[64] = {

        0xd76aa478,     0xe8c7b756, 0x242070db, 0xc1bdceee,
        0xf57c0faf, 0x4787c62a,     0xa8304613, 0xfd469501,
        0x698098d8, 0x8b44f7af, 0xffff5bb1, 0x895cd7be,
        0x6b901122,     0xfd987193,     0xa679438e, 0x49b40821,

        0xf61e2562, 0xc040b340,     0x265e5a51,     0xe9b6c7aa,
        0xd62f105d, 0x2441453,  0xd8a1e681, 0xe7d3fbc8,
        0x21e1cde6, 0xc33707d6,     0xf4d50d87,     0x455a14ed,
        0xa9e3e905, 0xfcefa3f8,     0x676f02d9,     0x8d2a4c8a,

        0xfffa3942, 0x8771f681,     0x6d9d6122,     0xfde5380c,
        0xa4beea44,     0x4bdecfa9,     0xf6bb4b60,     0xbebfbc70,
        0x289b7ec6,     0xeaa127fa,     0xd4ef3085, 0x4881d05,
        0xd9d4d039,     0xe6db99e5,     0x1fa27cf8,     0xc4ac5665,

        0xf4292244,     0x432aff97,     0xab9423a7,     0xfc93a039,
        0x655b59c3,     0x8f0ccc92,     0xffeff47d,     0x85845dd1,
        0x6fa87e4f,     0xfe2ce6e0,     0xa3014314,     0x4e0811a1,
        0xf7537e82,     0xbd3af235,     0x2ad7d2bb,     0xeb86d391,
 };

static const uint rconst_cpu[16] =
{
   7, 12, 17, 22,   5,  9, 14, 20,   4, 11, 16, 23,   6, 10, 15, 21
};

 void init_constants(uint *target_cpu)
 {
   cudaMemcpyToSymbol(k, k_cpu, sizeof(k));
   cudaMemcpyToSymbol(rconst, rconst_cpu, sizeof(rconst));
   if(target_cpu) { cudaMemcpyToSymbol(target, target_cpu, 4*4); };
 }

//
// MD5 routines (straight from Wikipedia's MD5 pseudocode description)
//

__device__ inline uint leftrotate (uint x, uint c)
{
   return (x << c) | (x >> (32-c));
}

__device__ inline uint r(const uint i)
{
   return rconst[(i / 16) * 4 + i % 4];
}

// Accessor for w[16] array. Naively, this would just be w[i]; however, this
// choice leads to worst-case-scenario access pattern wrt. shared memory
// bank conflicts, as the same indices in different threads fall into the
// same bank (as the words are 16 uints long). The packing below causes the
// same indices in different threads of a warp to map to different banks. In
// testing this gave a ~40% speedup.
//
// PS: An alternative solution would be to make the w array 17 uints long
// (thus wasting a little shared memory)
//
__device__ inline uint &getw(uint *w, const int i)
{
    return w[(i+threadIdx.x) % 16];
}

__device__ inline uint getw(const uint *w, const int i) // const- version
{
     return w[(i+threadIdx.x) % 16];
}


__device__ inline uint getk(const int i)
{
  return k[i];  // Note: this is as fast as possible (measured)
}

__device__ void step(const uint i, const uint f, const uint g, uint &a, uint &b, uint &c, uint &d, const uint *w)
{
   uint temp = d;
   d = c;
   c = b;
   b = b + leftrotate((a + f + getk(i) + getw(w, g)), r(i));
   a = temp;
}

__device__ void inline md5(const uint *w, uint &a, uint &b, uint &c, uint &d)
{
  const uint a0 = 0x67452301;
  const uint b0 = 0xEFCDAB89;
  const uint c0 = 0x98BADCFE;
  const uint d0 = 0x10325476;

   //Initialize hash value for this chunk:
   a = a0;
   b = b0;
   c = c0;
   d = d0;

   uint f, g, i = 0;
   for(; i != 16; i++)
   {
      f = (b & c) | ((~b) & d);
      g = i;
      step(i, f, g, a, b, c, d, w);
   }

   for(; i != 32; i++)
   {
      f = (d & b) | ((~d) & c);
      g = (5*i + 1) % 16;
      step(i, f, g, a, b, c, d, w);
   }

   for(; i != 48; i++)
   {
      f = b ^ c ^ d;
      g = (3*i + 5) % 16;
      step(i, f, g, a, b, c, d, w);
   }

   for(; i != 64; i++)
   {
      f = c ^ (b | (~d));
      g = (7*i) % 16;
      step(i, f, g, a, b, c, d, w);
   }

   a += a0;
   b += b0;
   c += c0;
   d += d0;
}

 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 /////////////       Ron Rivest's MD5 C Implementation       //////////////////
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/***********************************************************************
** Copyright (C) 1990, RSA Data Security, Inc. All rights reserved. **
**                                                                  **
** License to copy and use this software is granted provided that   **
** it is identified as the "RSA Data Security, Inc. MD5 Message     **
** Digest Algorithm" in all material mentioning or referencing this **
** software or this function.                                       **
**                                                                  **
** License is also granted to make and use derivative works         **
** provided that such works are identified as "derived from the RSA **
** Data Security, Inc. MD5 Message Digest Algorithm" in all         **
** material mentioning or referencing the derived work.             **
**                                                                  **
** RSA Data Security, Inc. makes no representations concerning      **
** either the merchantability of this software or the suitability   **
** of this software for any particular purpose.  It is provided "as **
** is" without express or implied warranty of any kind.             **
**                                                                  **
** These notices must be retained in any copies of any part of this **
** documentation and/or software.                                   **
***********************************************************************/


/* F, G and H are basic MD5 functions: selection, majority, parity */
#define F(x, y, z) (((x) & (y)) | ((~x) & (z)))
#define G(x, y, z) (((x) & (z)) | ((y) & (~z)))
#define H(x, y, z) ((x) ^ (y) ^ (z))
#define I(x, y, z) ((y) ^ ((x) | (~z))) 

/* ROTATE_LEFT rotates x left n bits */
#define ROTATE_LEFT(x, n) (((x) << (n)) | ((x) >> (32-(n))))

/* FF, GG, HH, and II transformations for rounds 1, 2, 3, and 4 */
/* Rotation is separate from addition to prevent recomputation */
#define FF(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) \
  {(a) += F ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (uint)(ac); \
   (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
   (a) += (b); \
  }
#define GG(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) \
  {(a) += G ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (uint)(ac); \
   (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
   (a) += (b); \
  }
#define HH(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) \
  {(a) += H ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (uint)(ac); \
   (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
   (a) += (b); \
  }
#define II(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) \
   {(a) += I ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (uint)(ac); \
    (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
    (a) += (b); \
   }


/* Basic MD5 step. Transform buf based on in.*/
void inline __device__ md5_v2(const uint *in, uint &a, uint &b, uint &c, uint &d)
{
  const uint a0 = 0x67452301;
  const uint b0 = 0xEFCDAB89;
  const uint c0 = 0x98BADCFE;
  const uint d0 = 0x10325476;

  //Initialize hash value for this chunk:
   a = a0;
   b = b0;
   c = c0;
   d = d0;

       /* Round 1 */
       #define S11 7
       #define S12 12
       #define S13 17
       #define S14 22
       FF ( a, b, c, d, getw(in,  0), S11, 3614090360); /* 1 */
       FF ( d, a, b, c, getw(in,  1), S12, 3905402710); /* 2 */
       FF ( c, d, a, b, getw(in,  2), S13,  606105819); /* 3 */
       FF ( b, c, d, a, getw(in,  3), S14, 3250441966); /* 4 */
       FF ( a, b, c, d, getw(in,  4), S11, 4118548399); /* 5 */
       FF ( d, a, b, c, getw(in,  5), S12, 1200080426); /* 6 */
       FF ( c, d, a, b, getw(in,  6), S13, 2821735955); /* 7 */
       FF ( b, c, d, a, getw(in,  7), S14, 4249261313); /* 8 */
       FF ( a, b, c, d, getw(in,  8), S11, 1770035416); /* 9 */
       FF ( d, a, b, c, getw(in,  9), S12, 2336552879); /* 10 */
       FF ( c, d, a, b, getw(in, 10), S13, 4294925233); /* 11 */
       FF ( b, c, d, a, getw(in, 11), S14, 2304563134); /* 12 */
       FF ( a, b, c, d, getw(in, 12), S11, 1804603682); /* 13 */
       FF ( d, a, b, c, getw(in, 13), S12, 4254626195); /* 14 */
       FF ( c, d, a, b, getw(in, 14), S13, 2792965006); /* 15 */
       FF ( b, c, d, a, getw(in, 15), S14, 1236535329); /* 16 */

       /* Round 2 */
       #define S21 5
       #define S22 9
       #define S23 14
       #define S24 20
       GG ( a, b, c, d, getw(in,  1), S21, 4129170786); /* 17 */
       GG ( d, a, b, c, getw(in,  6), S22, 3225465664); /* 18 */
       GG ( c, d, a, b, getw(in, 11), S23,  643717713); /* 19 */
       GG ( b, c, d, a, getw(in,  0), S24, 3921069994); /* 20 */
       GG ( a, b, c, d, getw(in,  5), S21, 3593408605); /* 21 */
       GG ( d, a, b, c, getw(in, 10), S22,   38016083); /* 22 */
       GG ( c, d, a, b, getw(in, 15), S23, 3634488961); /* 23 */
       GG ( b, c, d, a, getw(in,  4), S24, 3889429448); /* 24 */
       GG ( a, b, c, d, getw(in,  9), S21,  568446438); /* 25 */
       GG ( d, a, b, c, getw(in, 14), S22, 3275163606); /* 26 */
       GG ( c, d, a, b, getw(in,  3), S23, 4107603335); /* 27 */
       GG ( b, c, d, a, getw(in,  8), S24, 1163531501); /* 28 */
       GG ( a, b, c, d, getw(in, 13), S21, 2850285829); /* 29 */
       GG ( d, a, b, c, getw(in,  2), S22, 4243563512); /* 30 */
       GG ( c, d, a, b, getw(in,  7), S23, 1735328473); /* 31 */
       GG ( b, c, d, a, getw(in, 12), S24, 2368359562); /* 32 */

       /* Round 3 */
       #define S31 4
       #define S32 11
       #define S33 16
       #define S34 23
       HH ( a, b, c, d, getw(in,  5), S31, 4294588738); /* 33 */
       HH ( d, a, b, c, getw(in,  8), S32, 2272392833); /* 34 */
       HH ( c, d, a, b, getw(in, 11), S33, 1839030562); /* 35 */
       HH ( b, c, d, a, getw(in, 14), S34, 4259657740); /* 36 */
       HH ( a, b, c, d, getw(in,  1), S31, 2763975236); /* 37 */
       HH ( d, a, b, c, getw(in,  4), S32, 1272893353); /* 38 */
       HH ( c, d, a, b, getw(in,  7), S33, 4139469664); /* 39 */
       HH ( b, c, d, a, getw(in, 10), S34, 3200236656); /* 40 */
       HH ( a, b, c, d, getw(in, 13), S31,  681279174); /* 41 */
       HH ( d, a, b, c, getw(in,  0), S32, 3936430074); /* 42 */
       HH ( c, d, a, b, getw(in,  3), S33, 3572445317); /* 43 */
       HH ( b, c, d, a, getw(in,  6), S34,   76029189); /* 44 */
       HH ( a, b, c, d, getw(in,  9), S31, 3654602809); /* 45 */
       HH ( d, a, b, c, getw(in, 12), S32, 3873151461); /* 46 */
       HH ( c, d, a, b, getw(in, 15), S33,  530742520); /* 47 */
       HH ( b, c, d, a, getw(in,  2), S34, 3299628645); /* 48 */

       /* Round 4 */
       #define S41 6
       #define S42 10
       #define S43 15 
       #define S44 21
       II ( a, b, c, d, getw(in,  0), S41, 4096336452); /* 49 */
       II ( d, a, b, c, getw(in,  7), S42, 1126891415); /* 50 */
       II ( c, d, a, b, getw(in, 14), S43, 2878612391); /* 51 */
       II ( b, c, d, a, getw(in,  5), S44, 4237533241); /* 52 */
       II ( a, b, c, d, getw(in, 12), S41, 1700485571); /* 53 */
       II ( d, a, b, c, getw(in,  3), S42, 2399980690); /* 54 */
       II ( c, d, a, b, getw(in, 10), S43, 4293915773); /* 55 */
       II ( b, c, d, a, getw(in,  1), S44, 2240044497); /* 56 */
       II ( a, b, c, d, getw(in,  8), S41, 1873313359); /* 57 */
       II ( d, a, b, c, getw(in, 15), S42, 4264355552); /* 58 */
       II ( c, d, a, b, getw(in,  6), S43, 2734768916); /* 59 */
       II ( b, c, d, a, getw(in, 13), S44, 1309151649); /* 60 */
       II ( a, b, c, d, getw(in,  4), S41, 4149444226); /* 61 */
       II ( d, a, b, c, getw(in, 11), S42, 3174756917); /* 62 */
       II ( c, d, a, b, getw(in,  2), S43,  718787259); /* 63 */
       II ( b, c, d, a, getw(in,  9), S44, 3951481745); /* 64 */

   a += a0;
   b += b0;
   c += c0;
   d += d0;

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// The kernel (this is the entrypoint of GPU code)
// Loads the 64-byte word to be hashed from global to shared memory
// and calls the calculation routine
__global__ void md5_calc(uint *gwords, uint *hash, int realthreads)
{
  int linidx = (gridDim.x*blockIdx.y + blockIdx.x)*blockDim.x + threadIdx;  //assuming blockDim.y = 1 and threadIdx.y = 0, always
  if(linidx >= realthreads) { return; } // this check slows down the code by ~0.4% (measured)

  // load the dictionary word for this thread
  uint *word = &memory[0] + threadIdx.x*16;
  for(int i=0; i != 16; i++)
  {
        getw(word, i) = gwords[(linidx)*16+i];
  }

  // compute MD5 hash
  uint a, b, c, d;

  RSA_KERNEL(word, a, b, c, d);

  // return the hash
  hash[(linidx)*4+0] = a;
  hash[(linidx)*4+1] = b;
  hash[(linidx)*4+2] = c;
  hash[(linidx)*4+3] = d;
}

// The kernel (this is the entrypoint of GPU code)
// Loads the 64-byte word to be hashed from global to shared memory,
// calls the calculation routine, compares to target and flags if a match is found
__global__ void md5_search(uint *gwords, uint *succ, int realthreads)
{
  int linidx = (gridDim.x*blockIdx.y + blockIdx.x)*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; // assuming blockDim.y = 1 and threadIdx.y = 0, always
  if(linidx >= realthreads) { return; } // this check slows down the code by ~0.4% (measured)

  // load the dictionary word for this thread
  uint *word = &memory[0] + threadIdx.x*16;
  for(int i=0; i != 16; i++)
  {
      getw(word, i) = gwords[linidx*16+i];
  }

  // compute MD5 hash
  uint a, b, c, d;

  RSA_KERNEL(word, a, b, c, d);

  if(a == target[0] && b == target[1] && c == target[2] && d == target[3])
  {
      succ[0] = linidx;
      succ[3] = 1;
  }
}

 // A helper to export the kernel call to C++ code not compiled with nvcc
double execute_kernel(int blocks_x, int blocks_y, int threads_per_block, int shared_mem_required, int realthreads, uint *gpuWords, uint *gpuHashes, bool search)
{
  dim3 grid;
  grid.x = blocks_x; grid.y = blocks_y;

  unsigned int hTimer;
  CUT_SAFE_CALL( cutCreateTimer(&hTimer) );
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL( cudaThreadSynchronize() );
  CUT_SAFE_CALL( cutResetTimer(hTimer) );
  CUT_SAFE_CALL( cutStartTimer(hTimer) );

  if(search)
  {
      md5_search<<<grid, threads_per_block, shared_mem_required>>>(gpuWords, gpuHashes, realthreads);
  }
  else
  {
      md5_calc<<<grid, threads_per_block, shared_mem_required>>>(gpuWords, gpuHashes, realthreads);
  }

  CUT_CHECK_ERROR("md5_calc() execution failed\n");
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL( cudaThreadSynchronize() );
  CUT_SAFE_CALL( cutStopTimer(hTimer) );
  double gpuTime = cutGetTimerValue(hTimer);
  CUT_SAFE_CALL( cutDeleteTimer( hTimer) );

  return gpuTime;
}
```

Comment: The link you have posted is currently unavailable. Provide your post with a complete code or post another link. If I were you I would choose first option as links to external sites could become invalid.

Comment: @stuhlo I posted the complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUDA GPUs have a special kind of logical storage indicated by [`__constant__`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#constant) which basically uses a special hardware caching mechanism to improve access time to frequently accessed constant values used by a CUDA kernel.

The `rconst_cpu` array is just the CPU copy of the data (to be copied to the GPU `rconst` array, which lives in constant memory, as indicated by `__constant__`) that will live in this constant memory area on the GPU.

The `r` function (which runs on the GPU) takes index `i` passed to it, and and uses bits 4-5 (of `i`) to index into one of the 4 groups in the `rconst` array, and pick a value out of the selected group using bits 0-1 (of `i`).

Regarding this syntax:

```
w[(i+threadIdx.x) % 16];
```

As you indicated, `threadIdx` is [part of the CUDA extensions to C/C++](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy).  It is a built-in variable that is only available in device code.  It comes in 3 dimensions: `.x`, `.y`, and `.z`, and it is used in device code to differentiate thread behavior.  The CUDA architecture essentially provides a single set of code to be executed by all threads.  A principal mechanism that allows threads to do something different from each other are these built-in variables.

In this particular example, the assumption is that multiple threads will be executing the code that makes this particular array reference.  Each thread will then access an element out of the `w` array that is equal to the `i` index passed to the function, plus the unique `threadIdx.x` index that each thread has.  Therefore each thread will access a different element of `w` based on this reference.

These questions seem to reflect basic aspects of C and CUDA.  I don't recommend you try and learn CUDA this way, and I believe a question like this could be easily closed since it clearly indicates a lack of understanding of CUDA, and perhaps also C.  One of the question closure reasons is as follows:

"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist"

Therefore my recommendation would be to get a [few hours of basic exposure to CUDA programming](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars) first, rather than just picking up code that looks foreign to you and asking others to decipher it, bit by bit.